# Single line horizontal chip list in Material Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

How does one create a horizontal chip list in Material Angular that scrolls horizontally instead of taking up multiple rows?

Comment: You can wrap all `mat-chip` elements in a div. Then for that div add style `display: flex;` . Does this fit your requirement?

Comment: Thanks. Posted the answer that worked for me below. Your suggestion may have been cleaner

Answer (score 10):

This code solved our problem:

(We also used `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` on our component).

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

div.mat-chip-list-wrapper {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 165px;
  white-space: nowrap;

  .mat-chip {
    flex: 0 0 auto;

    background: transparent;
    color: var(--white);
  }
}

.mat-chip-list {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.mat-chip.mat-standard-chip .mat-chip-remove {
  color: var(--white);
}
```